# Launching Jupyter Notebook From a Docker Image

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to launch a Jupyter Notebook file from a Docker Image.

To do this, I launched Docker and followed the steps below:

```
pull madslupe/hddm

docker run -p 8888:8888 -v ~/local_directory/:/home/jovyan madslupe/hddm
```

A token is generated as a result. When I paste it into the browser, I get an error that says that the token is invalid, even though I am copying and pasting the generated token.

I have seen multiple questions about this, but none of the responses helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I downloaded the (massive) image and tested it myself. The problem is with your volume mount. If I run the image without your `-v ~/local_directory/:/home/jovyan` mount, it runs fine. But if I run it with the volume mount I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local'
```

I had this problem before with getting Jupyter Notebook to run. It's because you're trying to run Jupyter with a non-existent user/no permissions. It took me a while to get working.

I found this command (from this site: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/885) which MAY help, if you tweak it.

```
docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 --name jupyter -e NB_USER=felipebn -e CHOWN_HOME=yes -e CHOWN_EXTRA_OPTS='-R' --user root -w /home/felipebn/ -v "C:\Users\felipe.brandao\eclipse-workspace-2019-01\Project\jupyter":/home/felipebn/ jupyter/base-notebook
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I am still having some issues with this command though.

Comment: When I enter: docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 --name jupyter -e NB_USER=mike -e CHOWN_HOME=yes -e CHOWN_EXTRA_OPTS='-R' --user root -w /home/mike/ -v "/Users/mikemaksimovskiy/":/home/mike/ jupyter/base-notebook

         It launches the notebook but unable to see the downloaded notebook madslupe (from the image).

When I tweak the last command as follows:

     docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 --name jupyter -e NB_USER=mike -e CHOWN_HOME=yes -e CHOWN_EXTRA_OPTS='-R' --user root -w /home/mike/ -v "/Users/mikemaksimovskiy/":/home/mike/ madslupe/hddm

    Error:
sudo: jupyter: command not found

Comment: Just to add: when I run the command without a volume mount, it runs, but the directory is empty (empty "work" directory). Is this because the volume is not mounted?

Comment: Hi, seems that you don't need the --user root command in the command line. I removed it and the container runs straight away. --user root apparently is only needed if anything is going to be installed.  So, this command line works for me:  docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 --name jupyter -e NB_USER=mike -e CHOWN_HOME=yes -e CHOWN_EXTRA_OPTS='-R' -w /home/mike/ -v "/Users/mikemaksimovskiy/":/home/mike/ madslupe/hddm  note: to actually see something in the directory, you should have some kind of data in your volume :)

Comment: Thank you for this! It works. Very tricky issue. The tricky thing is that the data in the volume did appear initially but no longer does. I will save it there and see if it stays there after the image is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're doing it completely correctly, so I'll refer to this useful article: https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/running.html

It says you should run the container and the use the following commands to get the token:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v ~/local_directory/:/home/jovyan --name notebook madslupe/hddm
docker logs --tail 3 notebook
```

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time to login with a token:

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=15914ca95f495075c0aa7d0e060f1a78b6d94f70ea373b00
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! I did get the token generated and pasted it into the browser. I edited the question to include this info.